# dns for dynamic IP

Tags: dns, ip, dyndns

I'd like to know the best solutions to get a public static dns or IP adress to access a computer on a routed network (for example to access from the internet a PC in my home LAN).

I heard about no-ip and dyndns.

Are they good? which one is the best? Is it really reliable ?

Comment: This sounds more like a question for Server Fault than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

This is a server fault question, but to provide an answer anyway, I use dyndns.org, it works nicely ( most routers even have auto update support built in, and for those that dont there desktop updater works just fine. )

dyndns.org seems to have amazingly reliable uptime, and i cant talk for noip as i have never used it. give them a try and see which one you like more.

Comment: sorry i didn't know server fault, altough I thought it wasn't the right place to post it.
I'll post there next time !
The problem anyway is that I can't really try both since I have to make my server available asap.
Then I'll follow your advices and try dyndns firstly.
thanks

Comment: http://dyndns.org is now not free anymore. https://www.dlinkddns.com works instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are several free dynamic DNS services like afraid.org, dynu.com etc. You may want to go with one which has an open API so that you can use it from within your application.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can have a look at https://www.good-dns.net/
Very simple to use, provides a URL for automatic IP update, so suitable for dynamic IPs.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot options available - as far as I know dyn.org are not free for while already. And I am using https://myonlineportal.net
But you have to test by yourself and figure out which suit best for you. Sometimes it's just the available domain name.